# Prove expression $\sum_{d | n} \phi(d)\cdot\tau(\frac{n}{d}) = \sigma(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For natural numbers $n,d$
> $$\sum_{d | n} \phi(d)\cdot\tau\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = \sigma(n).$$

Some clarifications:

1. $\phi(d)$ - Euler function
2. $\tau(\frac{n}{d})$ - number of positive divisors of the natural number $\frac{n}{d}$
3. $\sigma(n)$ - sum of divisors of a natural number n

I tried to prove this expression, but I still can’t do it...

I need your help and hints...

Comment: The LHS is a Dirichlet convolution of two multiplicative functions and thus itself multiplicative. That means you only have to verify the identity for prime powers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're dealing with multiplicative functions on the left side, we know that the Dirichlet convolution will also be multiplicative, therefore, let's evaluate the left side when $n = p^k$ where $p$ is prime.

$\{ d, d \vert p^k\} = \{1,p,p^2,...,p^k\}$

$$\sum_{m=0}^k \phi(p^m) \cdot \tau (p^{k-m}) = \sum_{m=0}^k \phi(p^m) \cdot  (k-m+1) = \phi(1)(k+1) +\\ + \sum_{m=1}^k p^{m-1}(p-1)(k-m+1)$$

so

$$\sum_{m=0}^k \phi(p^m) \cdot \tau (p^{k-m})  = k+1 + (p-1)\sum_{m=1}^k p^{m-1}(k-m+1) = k+1 + \frac{p(p^k-1)-k(p-1)}{p-1}=$$

$$= 1 + \frac{p(p^k-1)}{p-1} = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1} = (1+p+p^2+...+p^k) = \sigma(p^k)$$

so this is one way to do it

Answer (score 2):

The functions $\phi$ and $\tau$ are multiplicative in the sense that $\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n)$ whenever $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, and similarly for $\tau$.

A property of multiplicative functions if $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative, then so is their convolution
$$
  (f \star g)(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} f(d) g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).
$$

Indeed, suppose that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Every divisor of $mn$ is uniquely of the form $xy$ where $x$ is a divisor of $m$ and $y$ is a divisor of $n$. We then have that
$$
  (f \star g)(mn) = \sum_{x \mid m} \sum_{y \mid n} f(xy) g\left( \frac{m}{x} \cdot \frac{n}{y} \right) = \sum_{x \mid m} \sum_{y \mid n} f(x) f(y) g\left( \frac{m}{x} \right) g\left( \frac{n}{y} \right)
$$
where we have used that $\gcd(x, y) = \gcd(m/x, n/y) = 1$ to rewrite $f(xy)$ as $f(x) f(y)$, and similarly for $g$.

The sum is then equal to
$$
  \sum_{x \mid m} f(x) g\left( \frac{m}{x} \right) \sum_{n \mid y} f(y) g\left( \frac{n}{y} \right) = (f \star g)(m) \cdot (f \star g)(n).
$$

This implies that it is sufficient to prove that your identity holds for powers of prime numbers. Let $n = p^k$. Then we have that
$$
  \sum_{d \mid n} \phi(d) \tau\left( \frac{n}{d} \right) = \sum_{m = 0}^{k} \phi(p^m) \tau(p^{k - m}) = \phi(p^0) \tau(p^k) + \sum_{m = 1}^{k} (p^m - p^{m - 1}) (k - m + 1)
$$
where I have split off the $m = 0$ term so that I can use the formula $\phi(p^m) = p^{m} - p^{m - 1}$ for $m \geq 1$.

We can rewrite the quantity $k - m + 1$ as $\sum_{i = m}^{k} 1$, and then exchange the order of summation to get
$$
  \tau(p^k) + \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \sum_{m = 1}^{i} (p^m - p^{m - 1}) = (k + 1) + \sum_{i = 1}^{k} (p^i - 1) = k + p^0 + \sum_{i = 1}^{k} p^i - k = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} p^i = \sigma\left( p^k \right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

This might be considered cheating, but I think this perspective is worth giving an overview of. Once you prove that the set of multiplicative functions with the Dirichlet convolution form an abelian group, we can deduce this without too much work knowing some common identities which aren't too difficult to prove for prime powers, thus hold for all natural numbers.

Let's define our functions $u$ give $u(n)=1$, $N$ give $N(n)=n$, $\delta$ gives $\delta(1)=1$ and $0$ otherwise (the identity of the group), and $\mu$ the typical Mobius function.

The identities we should know are,
$$\mu \star N = \phi$$
$$u \star \mu = \delta$$
$$u \star N = \sigma$$
$$u \star u = \tau$$

Now we can combine them as follows,

$$\phi \star \tau = (N \star \mu) \star (u \star u) = N \star \delta \star u = N \star u = \sigma$$

Comment: I realize it's a bit terse - I didn't want to obfuscate the thought process. If there's anything that I've taken for granted here that feels too far, I'm happy to amend it.

Comment: I think that some people are downvoting answers because they think that the question is bad, not because they think that the answer is bad.